# iText. How to set field's value type and how to find out this value type

Tags: itext

Is it possible to set specific value type for text field? For example only integers from one up to five? And if so is there a way to find out the value type that's required for this kind of field?

Comment: That is done using Javascript. If you want to know the possible value of a field, you need to understand the Javascript that corresponds with that field.